# Execution reverted when calling view function

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";

/**
 * @title SampleERC20
 * @dev Create a sample ERC20 standard token
 */
contract SampleERC20 is ERC20 {

    constructor(string memory tokenName, string memory tokenSymbol) ERC20(tokenName, tokenSymbol) {}

    function token0ToToken1(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint) {
        IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
        ERC20 token0 = ERC20(pair.token0());
        (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();
        uint k = (Res0/Res1)*(10**token0.decimals());
        return(amount/k);
    }
}
```

When calling token0ToToken1 returns:

```
call to SampleERC20.token0ToToken1 errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "execution reverted",
  "data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012"
}
```

How can i get more information from the data field?

Answer (score 3):

This is a revert produced by an assertion failure. You will find the `0x4e487b71` bytes in your tx receipt's `data` field which is the sign of a critical error. At the end of the bytedata, the `12` is the error code which is:

> `0x12: If you divide or modulo by zero (e.g. 5 / 0 or 23 % 0).`

Therefore I would check these lines from your code:

```
uint k = (Res0/Res1)*(10**token0.decimals());
return(amount/k);
```

Luckily there is a list with the specific error codes you can encounter related to panics.

- 0x01: If you call assert with an argument that evaluates to false.
- 0x11: If an arithmetic operation results in underflow or overflow outside of an unchecked { ... } block.
- 0x12: If you divide or modulo by zero (e.g. 5 / 0 or 23 % 0).
- 0x21: If you convert a value that is too big or negative into an enum type.
- 0x31: If you call .pop() on an empty array.
- 0x32: If you access an array, bytesN or an array slice at an out-of-bounds or negative index (i.e. x[i] where i >= x.length or i < 0).
- 0x41: If you allocate too much memory or create an array that is too large.
- 0x51: If you call a zero-initialized variable of internal function type.